# 2-sample bootstrap hypothesis test - comparing locations but different estimators in two samples

Tags: hypothesis-testing, self-study, bootstrap

I have two independent samples **X** and **Y** where $x_i \sim F$ and $y_i \sim G$. Two different estimators A and B map **X** to $x_0$ and **Y** to $y_0$ respectively. I'd like to compare $x_0$ and $y_0$. 
The method addressed in https://web.as.uky.edu/statistics/users/pbreheny/621/F12/notes/10-11.pdf isn't suitable as I have two different estimators.

What bootstrap hypothesis test should I use?

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved. Construct a confidence interval from the difference between the estimates of bootstrap samples of **X** and **Y**.